# Do Twitter Web Intents work for Android Chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, twitter

I'm using the Twitter Web Intent feature to help the mobile browser trigger the use of the native app in Android Chrome. However it doesn't seem to work: Is there a known issue where this doesn't work in Android Chrome?

(I've tested this inside an email using the Android Gmail App as well as the standard Browser, and it will trigger the app suggestion dialog box.)

Answer (score 0):

Intent triggering is working with Chrome. You can use different applications to see if it is working. I didn't know that Twitter Android app is filtering the web urls of their site. Are you sure they do that?

Comment: I just did another test on my Android Chrome (18.0.1025469), and there is no intent pop up screen: http://play.meyouand.us/121224-intent/twitter1.html  Do you get an intent pop up when you try clicking on the test button as well?

Comment: I am telling you that twitter does not filter that intent at all. No matter what you do, you cannot do that.